# Does Quarkus provides any solution for joining websockets together like in socket.io?

Tags: java, rest, sockets, websocket, quarkus

**Problem**
I am currently working on a JAVA Quarkus backend and I am trying to solve the problem of communtication between users in different so called "rooms" like socket io does it with joining the sockets together ([https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/](https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms).

[image: Room architecture]

Basically I want to implement the functionality shown in the image above in Quarkus with WebSockets.

**What have I tried?**
I have found a web-socket solution on the official quarkus website (https://quarkus.io/guides/websockets) but with the provided solution, there is no way to join the websockets together and create these "rooms"/lobbies like in socket io.

The provided code block has a single session for every user:

```
Map<String, Session> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("username") String username) {
        broadcast("User " + username + " joined");
        sessions.put(username, session);
    }
```

The architecture of the provided quarkus websocket solution looks like this:

[image: Single session-architecture]

**My questions**

- Is there a way to join a different session together or to create a custom session by PathParams?
- Are there any useful Java libraries providing such lobby/room/join functionality equivalent to socket.io in js?
- Is the provided code somehow changeable to achieve the goal?

Comment: you need to use something like a message broker (JMS) to accomplish this. Each incoming chat message from websocket should push the message to a topic, and then every instance of your server should broadcast it to the subscribed websocket sessions.

Comment: you mean something like apache kafka?